# Bash script multiple if express groups

Tags: bash, syntax

I am new to bash scripts, I am trying to group multiple expressions in my if statement

```
minuteRun = $1
if 
[
    [ [ $minuteRun -eq 25 ] &&  [ $HR != 01] && [ $HR != 13 ] ] || 
    [ [ $minuteRun -eq 50 ] && [ $HR -eq 01 || $HR -eq 13 ] ]
]   
 then
```

I call it as `./script.sh 45`

Here are the errors

- ./script.sh: line 25: [: missing `]'
- ./script.sh: line 26: [: too
  many arguments
- ./script.sh: line 27: [: too many arguments
- ./script.sh: line 27: 12: command not found
- ./script.sh: line 28: ]:
  command not found

Comment: Don't forget that the command `[` is just an alternative spelling to the command `test`, so you basically wrote `if test test test $minuteRun -eq 25 ....` and so on, with newline characters interspersed, which makes it even worse. Actually, bash already bails out at the very first `[` , because it does not see a terminating `]` on the same line.

Comment: see also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntax errors esp. space between brackets e.g. `[ [`

It is better to use arithmetic context in bash for this using `(( ...))`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

minuteRun=$1

if 
((
    ( minuteRun == 25 && HR != 1 && HR != 13 )
    || 
    ( minuteRun == 50 && ( HR == 1 || HR == 13 ) )
))   
 then
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally i'd use `case` for this

```
minuteRun=50 HR=01
case $minuteRun:$HR in
     50:01|50:13) echo ok;;
      *:01|*:13 ) echo fail;;
esac
```